# Limit who can delete/reactivate subscription on Azure

Tags: azure

Was wondering if there's such cases where we can limit certain users or grant specific users to cancel the subscription(via policy maybe?). For example by default Owner can Cancel or Reactivate, but the goal is to limit only XYZ Group to able to Cancel/Reactivate the subscription, not even owner of subscription can cancel/reactivate it.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/role-based-access-control/deny-assignments-portal#list-deny-assignments

Comment: Policy wont help you since it does not have context of the user :( so if you apply policy it will be same for everyone